# struts2 if condition with property or tiles-attribute doesnt work

Tags: iterator, struts2, tiles

i have problems with my if condition using struts 2.
I have a tiles-definition using a put-list-attribute with list-attributes as menuitems.

In my menu.jsp i iterate over the put-list to render all my menuitems.
Now i try to check if the value of my item contains a special character.
Here is my code:

tiles.xml

```
<definition name="start.menu" template="/WEB-INF/menu.jsp" >
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Hauptmenu" />       
        <put-list-attribute name="webThemes" >
                <add-list-attribute>
                    <add-attribute value="Test" id="name"/>
                    <add-attribute value="atest" />
                </add-list-attribute>
                <add-list-attribute>
                    <add-attribute value="System Test"/>
                    <add-attribute value="test" />
                </add-list-attribute>
        </put-list-attribute>
    </definition>
```

menu.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/tiles-jsp" prefix="tiles" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/tiles-extras-jsp" prefix="tilesx" %>

<%-- Push tiles attributes in page context --%>
<tiles:importAttribute />

<tilesx:useAttribute id="list" name="webThemes" classname="java.util.List" />
<table  class="menu" border="0px" width="100%" cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="0px" >

<s:iterator value="#attr.webThemes" var="item">

    <s:if test="%{#item.value[1].contains('a')}">
        <s:set var="link" value="111"/>
    </s:if>
    <s:else>
        <s:set var="link" value="#item.value[1]"/>
    </s:else>
<tr>
 
  <td valign="top" >
       
      <font size="-1">
        <a href="<s:property value="#link"/>"
            class="menu">
            <s:property value="#item.value[0]" />
            <s:property value="#item.value[1]" />
       </a>
      </font>
  </td>
</tr>

</s:iterator>
```

But the condition is always false.
I tried different approaches but nothing worked:

```
<s:if test="%{#item.value[1].contains('a')}">
<s:if test="#item.value[1].contains('a')">
<s:if test='%{#item.value[1].contains("a")}'>

<s:set var="itemvalue" value="#item.value[1]"/>
<s:property value="itemvalue"/>
    <s:if test='%{#itemvalue.contains("a")}'>
    <s:if test='#itemvalue.contains("a")'>

<s:if test='%{#item.value[1] == "atest"}'>
```

So how can i get the condition working? What am i doing wrong?
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok... i tried 2 days until i posted my question.
but after posting a found a working solution in an hour...:

`<s:if test='(#item.value[1].value).startsWith("a")'>`

Comment: (Noting that these are different things; containing, and starting with, are very different conditions.)

Comment: yes, you are right, startsWith and contains are different things, but both conditions work.

Comment: Understood, just wanted to point it out :)